# How map authorizations (and other sub-infos) in oData structure

Tags: odata, sapui5

This is the base schema of oData EDM:
[image] [thanks for the image Filippo](http://tesi.cab.unipd.it/46703/1/tesi.pdf)

I have my db structure:

```
Product (Code, Description, IVA, Price)
|n
|
|
|
|1
Purchase(ID, Product, Customer)
```

I want expose my data using oData; I can map in a natural way Product and Purchase in two EntitySet: **ProductSet** and **PurchaseSet**.

If I require for example all items of ProductSet I receive a collection of 100 products; each product have 4 properties, for example:

```
{
   Code:01, 
   Description: "blue pen", 
   IVA: "19", 
   Price: "2.99"
}
```

Ok but based on the user logged, the business logic before oData want send me more information (for example the ***editable*** sub property):

```
{
   Code: {value:01, editable:false}, 
   Description: {value:"blue pen", editable:false}, 
   IVA: {value:19, editable:true}, 
   Price: {value:"2.99", editable:true}
}
```

(I can't sent the new information in this mode, I have only entity sets and properties...)

What is the right way to map editable infos in EDM? A New Property??

Comment: I use editable proertiy to map the same property in the Input component in my OpenUI5 app https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputStates/preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a ComplexType that will have the properties of value and editable. So the properties of your Entity will refer to the ComplexType.